# Iterator category for circular buffer

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, language-lawyer, c++20

I tried to implement circular buffer of the following kind.

For simplicity I assume that circular buffer is just a container adapter (like `std::stack`) for containers having [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator). Container resized/filled with values somehow, then emplaced into adapter. After that, size of underlying container should not change.

Obviously `c.begin() == c.end()` for circular buffer. Some algorithms (say, range based for loop) not work as expected for circular buffer (instead of `for (;;)` one can use `assert(!c.empty()); auto beg = std::begin(c), it = beg; do { f(it); } while (++it != beg);` to traverse circular buffer).

The main problem arised when I try to sort circular buffer using `std::sort`. Inheritance of the iterator category from underlying container is not fair for circular buffer iterators. Iterator of circular buffer should be almost [*RandomAccessIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator), but not strictly total ordered (`<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` are undefined). Implementation of `std::sort` can use `operator <` internally (and does).

I can't define my own iterator category (say, *ModularIterator*) and insert it between existent categories (such that `std::is_base_of_v<std::bidirectional_iterator_tag, my_iterator_tag>` and `std::is_base_of_v<my_iterator_tag, std::random_access_iterator_tag>`). Also algorithms are not points of customization.

I don't want to set `iterator_category` to `std::bidirectional_iterator_tag`, because `std::equal_range` would not work in logarithmic time.

Does strict total ordering of *RandomAccessIterator* really needed somewhere in algorithms or can it be avoided?

Is there way to make `<algorithm>`s work for the circular buffer?

Is it oversight in the Standard that there is no iterator category that fit non-ordered iterators, which can be advanced for any step for `O(1)`?

Example: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GH1JF4WK2IUUCRHg

Comment: It sounds like you want the standard library to adapt to your iterator type. It seems like you're assuming that your iterator type is basically an alias for a raw pointer. You should forget this preconception and write an iterator that is compatible with the the standard library functions. Make your iterator random access by calculating the actual element position yourself within the iterator. Make sure `begin` isn't `end`.

Comment: "Obviously `c.begin() == c.end()` for circular buffer." This is not obvious at all. It is an incorrect implementation.

Comment: @Barry why incorrect? Is there statement in Standard, that prohibit?

Comment: You should make `c.begin() == c.end()` only when the buffer is empty. When it's full, you must make sure they're different.  Same with `operator<`.  You must _define_ `operator<` so that the user of the iterator has no idea it's using modulo arithmatic under the covers.

Comment: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf  § 27.2.2  documents the part of the C++ standard that prohibits

Comment: Currently I can"t imagine design where this is not true and adapter remains useful. Any ideas?

Comment: For these various reasons, a common implementation is to make sure there's always at least one empty 'space' in the circular buffer, so that the begin==end only when the container is empty.

Comment: I want to cross end seamlessly, like container is endless.

Comment: Ok, end can be sentinel

Comment: @TomilovAnatoliy I think you may have missed or dismissed the recommendation that you should not think of your iterators as just raw pointers to elements in your circular buffer. You will have to write a `class` type that behaves like other iterators.

Comment: Because this is how the iterator abstraction works. `c.begin() == c.end()` implies an empty range. Just because your storage is circular doesn't mean the range is empty - the point of the abstraction is to separate the algorithms from the storage. It is up to you to make sure your iterators do the right thing for your storage (i.e. `++i`, `i == j`, `*i`, `i + n`, `j - i`, etc. all are meaningful). And yes, your iterators _should_ be random access iterators (since that should be a cheap operation to provide).

Comment: range-v3 experimented with cyclic iterators once; [it was eventually abandoned "as a hopeless bug farm"](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/pull/913).

Comment: @Barry how `operator <` can be arranged for iterators of circular buffers?

Comment: I want to be able to start at position `i` and finish at position `i - 1`

Comment: Start simpler - get `++i`, `i == j`, and `*i` to all do the right thing.

Comment: why don't you look at boost::circular_buffers iterator [implementation](https://github.com/boostorg/circular_buffer/blob/develop/include/boost/circular_buffer/details.hpp). it is random access.

Comment: @TomilovAnatoliy You may want to make your iterator internally count how many times it has crossed the border and provide something like `begin(i)` and `end(i)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Obviously `c.begin() == c.end()` for circular buffer. Some algorithms (say, range based for loop) not work as expected for circular buffer

Correction: no range-based algorithm works (meaningfully) for such a range because a range where the begin and end iterators are the same is empty. That's the *definition* of an empty range.

What you need is an iterator that knows, not just what position it is within the buffer, but which *cycle* it is on. A begin iterator might be on position index 0, cycle 0, while the end iterator is on position index 0, cycle 1. The two iterators would *not* compare equal. And when you increment an iterator past the cycle boundary, it increments the cycle count by 1. The reverse goes for decrementing across the cycle boundary.

Essentially, a circular buffer iterator ought to represent an infinitely traversible range of values.

The part about the total order is kind of a red herring. Yes, random access iterators need a total order, but the fact that you want begin and end to be equal and not be an empty range is a fundamental design problem with your iterator. Once you fix that, the ability to totally order the infinite range naturally falls out.